# AutoMapper assign property from parent type property

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

is there i way in autoMapper to assign child class property from parent class property. I have looked at other example out there but didn't quite get what I need so posting my issue here.

here's code

```
   class ParentDB {
       public int id;
       public DateTime CreatedDate;
       public string Name;
    }

   class ChildDB {
      public int id;
      publi string Name;
      public int Number; 
   }

   class ParentViewModel  : IMapFrom <ParentDB> {
     pulic int id;
     pulic string Name;
     public ChildViewModel child;
    }

    class ChildViewModel : IMapFrom <ChildDB> {
       public int Id;
       pulic string Name;
        pulic DateTime ParentCreated;
    }

public interface IMapFrom<T>
    {   
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
    }
```

Problem is that "ParentCreated" time in ChildViewMode needs to come from ParentDB. I have tried following with no success

```
 class ParentViewModel  : IMapFrom <ParentDB> {
     pulic int id;
     pulic string Name;
     public ChildViewModel child;
     public DateTime CreatedDate;

     public void Mapping(Profile profile)
      {
        profile.CreateMap<ParentDB, ParentViewModel>()
           .AfterMap( (s,d) => d.ChildViewModel.ParentCreated = d.CreatedDate);
      }
    }


var children = await Context.ParentDB
               .ProjectTo<ParentViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
               .ToListAsync()
```

with above although ParentViewModel.CreatedDate has date, ChildViewModel.ParentCreated is null. can some please explain why its not assigning date in AfterMap and hwo can this be fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not how to do the map in the way you shared, since I can't see the `IMapFrom <T>` interface.

Maybe you can try below:

```
var parent = new ParentDB { id = 1, Name = "AA", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ParentDB, ParentViewModel>()
    .AfterMap((s, d) => d.ChildViewModel.ParentCreated = s.CreatedDate);
});
var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
ParentViewModel parentViewModel = mapper.Map<ParentViewModel>(parent);
```

Also you should initlize the ChildVewModel in the  ParentViewModel, otherwise it will occur a NullReference exception

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
    }
    public int id;
    public string Name;
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel;
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 'AfterMap((s, d) => d.ChildViewModel.ParentCreated = s.CreatedDate);'

We tried this as well but it still comes as null so then we copied it in ParentViewModel and then tried to assign it to the child via 
'.AfterMap( (s,d) => d.ChildViewModel.ParentCreated = d.CreatedDate);'
 but still null

Comment: have added interface if that helps

Comment: @Bhavesh it can map successfully with the above codes, you can see my screenshot. I am not understand why should it implement IMapFrom <T> .

Comment: could it be ProjectTo<> method?.